# Object destroys and doesnt play particle system

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm new to scripting in unity and I have a script that destroys an object when its health reaches `0`

```
var EnemyHealth : int = 10;

function DeductPoints (DamageAmount : int) {
    EnemyHealth -= DamageAmount;
}

function Update () {

    if (EnemyHealth <= 0) {
        GetComponent.<ParticleSystem>().Play();
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

When I run this script it works fine but when it gets destroyed, it doesn't play the animation and continues with destroying it.

Comment: You have destroyed the GameObject which contains the particle system, so it destroys the particle system too. You need to either delay the actual destruction of the object until the particle system is done playing, or place the particle system as a component on an empty GameObject and play it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How a particle system is supposed to play if you destroy the object holding it ?

Instantiate a prefab of the particle system with an auto-destrut parameter and do not make it a child of the object to destroy.

```
 if (EnemyHealth <= 0) {
    Instantiate( particlesPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation ) ;
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Edit : I thought particles systems had a parameter to destroy automatically themselves at the end of the emission but I can't find it. You may have to add a script to the prefab holding the particles system so as to destroy it after a given delay using the 2nd parameter of the [Destroy function](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html).

```
private void Start()
{
    ParticleSystem ps = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    Destroy( gameobject, ps.main.duration ) ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll see if my mind can comprehend that and give it a go! Thanks! ^-^

Comment: Thanks for the help :D